# Block parent stage until child stage closes

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, fxml

I have a controller on which an action event of my button opens a child stage. The issue is when I close the parent stage, the child stage also closes. I want to prevent parent stage from closing as long as child stage is open.

[image]

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("Message.fxml");
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
fxmlLoader.setLocation(url);
fxmlLoader.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());
root = (Parent)fxmlLoader.load(url.openStream());            
Stage stage = new Stage();
//stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
//stage.setFullScreen(true);
stage.setTitle("Welcome User");
stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 675, 
stage.show();
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set the followings:

```
stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
stage.initOwner(primaryStage);
```

You can get the primaryStage by putting it to static variable in main class:

```
public static Stage primaryStage;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    ...
}
```

then

```
stage.initOwner(MainApp.primaryStage);
```

Comment: its not working...when i am added   `stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
stage.initOwner((Stage)btnSearch.getScene().getWindow());` these lines with above code.its not working..how can i get primarystage from main class..

Comment: @uiuk can you help me once more..pls give me some suggestion at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19969567/running-javafx-app-with-hibernate-takes-too-much-time

Answer (score 0):

Just set the following property to your stage object...

```
stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
```