# using modality in a popup window javafx

Tags: javafx, modality

I kept a popup dialog on a pane and it came at the top of the other components. Now I want to disable accessing all the other components of the program. How to do it?

Comment: i also have same issue ...
try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953306/lock-parent-controller-till-child-controller-not-close

Comment: Thats a good question. I know all the given answers. But it seems to be a major mistake of the popup class. What is a popup good for, if you cannot set its modality?? I dont want to create a new "Stage" for a simple modal Input. I love java. But this is weird...

Answer (score 2):

The [popup](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Popup.html) API does not have an `initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);` method which is exactly what you want. In this case, you can make your popup window a stage and use the method mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

This is for `@Xsleek` in solution, example code:-

```
package popupexample;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBoxBuilder;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author reegan
 */
public class PopUpExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                popupErrorMsg();
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * The main() method is ignored in correctly deployed JavaFX application.
     * main() serves only as fallback in case the application can not be
     * launched through deployment artifacts, e.g., in IDEs with limited FX
     * support. NetBeans ignores main().
     *
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    public void popupErrorMsg() {
        final Stage myDialog = new Stage();
        myDialog.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        Button okButton = new Button("Ok");
        okButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                myDialog.close();
            }
        });
        Date todayDate = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Scene myDialogScene = new Scene(VBoxBuilder.create()
                .children(new Text("Please Enter Validate Date \n \t "+ dateFormat.format(todayDate)), okButton)
                .spacing(30)
                .alignment(Pos.CENTER)
                .padding(new Insets(10))
                .build());

        myDialog.setScene(myDialogScene);
        myDialog.show();
    }
}
```