# JavaFX Create a dialogpane

Tags: javafx

Main.class

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            // BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/MainWindow.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

```
package application;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class MainWindowController {

    public void buttonAction(ActionEvent event) {

        Stage dialog = new Stage();
        dialog.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(new Text(260, 260, "Hello World!")));
        // its Just for checking I want add .fxml here how can I do?
        dialog.setScene(scene);
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.MainWindowController">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="bt1" layoutX="154.0" layoutY="188.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonAction" text="Login" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

When I am clicking a login button one dialog is open which contain a form. 
How I do this? And my dialog contain only close button on title bar, when my dialog is open then I am not doing any action in my main MAinWindow. It just displays without focus. How can I do this?

Comment: Could you please improve the question? Right now it's hard to tell the parts that describe the desired behaviour from the parts that describe the actual behaviour.

Comment: JavaFX has an actual [DialogPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/DialogPane.html) class, which is a part of a [Dialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html) class, neither of which you use.  As your question has "dialogpane" in the title, I am curious if you are asking how to use these Dialog and DialogPane classes, or if you are just asking how to load FXML into a standard stage?  If the later, I'm not sure why you would ask as you already have code to do that in your main stage and it is no different for a child stage.

Comment: Part of your question seems to be a duplicate of: [Block parent stage until child stage closes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953306/block-parent-stage-until-child-stage-closes), but I'm not sure if that is all you are asking about either.

Comment: how to use the my customize dialog which create in scene builder I am take a dialogpane and insert text fields and buttons inside it now how to open this dialogpane as a dialog with only close button